# Multitasking Screenshot for Application does not run in background

Tags: ios, background, ios7, screenshot, multitasking

I have an app which does not run in the background. It is an animated kids app and I'd like it to close when the home button is tapped.

However, this results in a blank screenshot appearing in the iOS7 multitask switcher.

While not disrupting the operation of my app, it looks very unpolished in the switcher and my be hard for young users to identify.

Is there an official way to set this multitask switcher image or any trick for grabbing a screenshot before app closing? (There are plenty of tricks for apps that do run in background.)

Comment: iOS7 captures automatically a screenshot when the app goes to background. What do you mean by *close it* when the home button is tapped? Like kill it? Do you have some code to show what happens once the user presses the home button?

Comment: Well, my app does not run in background as set in the info.plist "does not run in the background" = YES. It seems to just take a black/blank screenshot, which looks really shabby in the switcher.

Comment: I see, so enabling `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` your app terminates when it goes to background. If you notice when you go to the multitask switcher the first time double tapping the home button directly from the app it shows the screenshot, but when you actually get out of the switcher the app closes. If it's so important to show the screenshot why do you actually close the app? Can't you keep it open and refresh/restart it upon coming to foreground?